# Javascript-only smooth scroll on button press

Tags: javascript, scroll

This site has a full-height image to start. Further content is located below the fold, with a 'scroll' element at the bottom of the image to prompt users to discover the rest of the content. On click, I've succeeded in making the site scroll down by 300 pixels. I want to do this smoothly, however. Here is my current code:

```
  window.onload = function () { 
    var scroll = document.getElementById("scroll");
    scroll.onclick = function () {
        var top = self.pageYOffset; 
        var goal = 300; 
        for(var i=0, l=goal; i<l; ++i) {
        window.scrollBy(0,1);
        }       
   }; 
};
```

This works for scrolling, but not smoothly. I thought that if I had the for loop, changing the window.scrollBy value to something like .001 would make it scroll more slowly (thus, smoothly), but that function doesn't seem to take decimal points.

Any tips? Technically it's fine now, but I'd rather add that last bit of polish. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code runs very fast and you don't see a smooth effect. You must use the `setInterval()` function, and scroll to the 300/n px in each iteration (n - number of iterations). Like this:

```
window.onload = function () { 
    var scroll = document.getElementById("scroll");
    scroll.onclick = function () {
        var currentScroll = 0; 
        var goal = 300;
        var step = goal/10
        var timer = setInterval( function () {
            if (currentScroll < goal) {
                window.scrollBy(0, step);
                currentScroll += step;
            } else {
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
        }, 50);
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...[example](http://css-tricks.com/examples/SmoothPageScroll/)

```
 $(function() {
      $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
          var target = $(this.hash);
          target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
          if (target.length) {
            $('html,body').animate({
              scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000);
            return false;
          }
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to avoid jQuery if I can, just to optimize performance since it's the only thing on the site I'd be using it for. Does this translate pretty easily?

Comment: How can I make my above example scroll smoothly? @mobilefire It works to scroll, just not smoothly. Do I really need a library like jQuery to accomplish this? I know Javascript has native animation functions but I don't know how to apply them to window.scrollBy

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for. I just want a smooth scroll-top-top, the link you posted looks more like a parallax effect. For such simple animation, loading an entire library seems superfluous.